# Google Analytics Behaviour Flow

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, google-analytics

I have an ionic app that is exported to both platforms [iOS and Android]
I was checking the behaviour flow in Google Analytics and got this view :
[image]

as we can see only signin /up pages are tracked, however the app has many other screens as shown in the below screenshot:[image]

I am using GoogleAnalytics.trackView("Screen Name") viewDidEnter() function, which is similar to viewDidAppear in iOS.

Can someone help me pointing out why I am not getting the correct flows?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

My best guess is that it's to do with the way you're reporting your views. I'm not hugely familiar with app reporting, but that Behavior Flows report requires your data to be structured into Sessions.

If, as I suspect is the case, you're accidentally telling Google Analytics that each page is the first page of a Session, then that report will not work at all.

The way to check if this is the case is to look at the Screens per Session value; if it's only fractionally over 1, then this is the issue.

The way to fix it is to look at your Screen View reporting, and make sure that you're not invoking a new Session each time.